# How does multitouch capability look to the API? (IPhone/OS X)

Tags: ios, macos, multi-touch

I don't have an iPhone and don't really want to pay $130 a month for a cell phone.  (I leave mine in the car most of the time, sometimes the entire weekend.)  But I covet the technology as a mobile computing platform.  (Cruel Fate.)  One of the things I like about it the most is the multitouch capability.

How does it look from an API standpoint?
Does the OS have "Gestures" that it knows and passes on an event based on what the user did, or is the application required to interpret a list of "touch and release" events?
How many points can it read?  2, 3... unlimited?
Does Mac OS X proper have this capability if you have a "Multitouch" capabible monitor?

Comment: As an aside you could get an iPod touch and play around with development on that for a much cheaper price (and no on-going fees).

Comment: Doesn't OSX/Cocoa come with SDK and a emulator? I know Palm OS always had that, so you could test drive the app without having the hardware.
Sorry for naive question, I'm not a iPerson :)

Comment: The free XCode running on a Mac has an iPhone Simulator, however, there is no way to actually use fingers to simulate mutli-touch.  The pseudo multi-touch input mechanism is crude.  One finger touch is just a mouse click.  Two finger touches are done with the option key and shift key in conjunction with a click.  It would have been nice if the trackpad were useful in mimicking the Cocoa Touch touch mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

You can always take a look at **[the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** to get a better idea of what is supported, but the general methods to implement are:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

When you tap down, touchesBegan is called with the set of touches that just began.  To retrieve all touches currently on the screen, retrieve `event.allTouches`.

Similarily obvious actions occur when a finger moves or is removed from the screen.  The `touchesCancelled` method is mostly used to support the `UIScrollView` which allows you to tap something inside a scroll view, then drag the scroll view itself rather that interact with the subview, if certain criteria are met (the scroll view would send a touches cancelled message to the subview when it starts scrolling).

There are no built-in gestures you can watch for to speak of, but there are built-in gestures that the system handles, like swiping across a row in a table to delete it, and pinch-zooming on a `UIScrollView`.